# Why is there a right margin on this image?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I have two `<button>` elements on my page, that both have one `<img>` inside. 
The problem is that both of these images have a right margin. Even though I didn't add it anywhere. I double checked the code twice, and I also made sure to manually exclude the right margin from the images:

```css
button img {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Here is the screenshot with developer tools open (Chrome)

[image]

You can see the margin when I hover over the margin box, but you can also see that `margin-right` for the image is `0px`.

This also happens to the image on the right.
I'm using Bootstrap, if that makes any difference.

Code with the buttons and images:

```
<section class="container-fluid" id="upload-buttons">   
  <button><img src="camera128.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Camera Clipart">Upload Image</button>
  <button><img src="video128.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Video Recorder Clipart">Upload Video</button>
</section>
```

Any solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: user `!important` to override the margin like `button img { margin-right : 0px !important;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the image has `display:block` but it is narrower than its parent. You can set the image's width 100% or set the margin's image as `0 auto` to center it.

In this snippet you can see the "blue" rectangle "have" 100 pixels `margin-right`. But it doesn't. The blue rectangle is your image.

```css
.wrapper {
 background:red;
 width:300px; 
 height:300px;
}

.inner {
 background:blue;
 width:200px;
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @aCodingN00b My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Amit singh's comment, you can override specificity rules with !important like so:

```
button img{
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
and [when to use it](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Comment: I added it, but the margin is still there??

Comment: I need code for troubleshooting, use jsfiddle.net and copy the important chunks.

Comment: Here, http://jsfiddle.net/e0hxy3Lj/ . But you won't be able to see the pictures, nor Bootstrap components.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `display: inline-block` for the parent element or the image element so it does not fill the empty space